# Rendering Liquid Template in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, template-engine, templating, liquid

I'm trying to have the "show" action for my pages controller render a Liquid template instead of the normal view. The template itself is stored in the database.

This is my show action:

```
  def show
    @organization = Organization.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
    @template = Liquid::Template.parse(Template.find(@organization.current_template))
    @page = @organization.pages.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render @template.render('page' => @page)}
      format.json { render json: @page }
    end
  end
```

However, it raises this exception:

```
uninitialized constant PagesController::Liquid
```

I'm a RoR newbie, so I'm assuming what's happening is that it's trying to find the Liquid class in the PagesController class, instead of realizing it's a class unto itself. I'm following the (somewhat sparse) instructions [here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers) as best I can.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include liquid in your Gemfile:

```
gem "liquid"
```

Then run `bundle install` and restart your rails server.

Comment: Ah, forgot to restart my server! Thank you!